# Не подключается mongodb, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting ECONNREFUSED

Tags: linux, база-данных, ubuntu, mongodb

Не могу запустить mongodb, Linux Ubuntu 20.04

```
root@dev-software:/home/dev# mongod
2021-08-18T15:21:46.612+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=14352 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=dev-software
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.8
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 8e540c0b6db93ce994cc548f000900bdc740f80a
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2021-08-18T15:21:46.613+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

root@dev-software:/home/dev# mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 611cfba45a
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

root@dev-software:/home/dev# sudo systemctl start mongod
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

root@dev-software:/home/dev# mongo show dbs
MongoDB shell version v4.4.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/show?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно у вас клиент не подключается к серверу - ведь сервер запускается с ошибкой и валится при инциализации. Обратите внимание на лог:

```
exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
now exiting
shutting down with code:100
```

Причина в том, что вас в `/etc/mongod.conf` наверняка написано

```
dbpath=/data/db
```

Так как этот каталог на диске отсутствует, сервер завершает работу.

Либо создайте каталог `/data/db`, либо поменяйте параметр `dbpath` на существующий каталог.

Как создать `/data/db`:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /data/db
```

Comment: но у меня в файле конфига задан другой путь...
`# mongodb.conf`

`# Where to store the data.`
`dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`

`#where to log`
`logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

`logappend=true`

`bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`
`#port = 27017`

Comment: @lbsmart Запустите `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` и добавьте в ваш вопрос вывод этой команды. Заодно покажите, что у вас возвращает команда `which mongod`